# Specify maximum length after comma in form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm using comma as the decimal separator in my input form:

HTML:

```
<form id="myform">
    <label for="field">Required, decimal number:</label>
    <input class="left" id="field" name="field">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>
```

I want to validate the input field to use only comma as the decimal separator AND allow the user to type only 2 decimals after the comma (it's a currency).

JS:

```
$.validator.addMethod("mynumber", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^(\d+|\d+,\d{1,2})$/.test(value);
}, "Por favor, introduza um número válido.");

$("#myform").validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            mynumber: true
        }
    }
});
```

I am already replacing the dot by a comma using Keypress. But how can I prevent the user from inserting more than 2 decimals after the comma?
JS:

```
$("#field").keypress(function (evt) {
    if (evt.which == 46) {
        $(this).val($(this).val() + ',');
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

You may see a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nuno/uSw5b/3/)

Comment: After each keypress, I would find comma position and cut everything 2 chars after it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#field").keypress(function (evt) {
    if (evt.which == 46) {
        $(this).val($(this).val() + ',');
        evt.preventDefault();
    }

    //The input of more than 2 numbers after the decimal point is prevented
    var foo = $(this).val();
    if( !foo.match(/^(\d)*,?(\d){0,1}$/) ){
         evt.preventDefault(); 
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pisi2012/uSw5b/7/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery Mask](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/).

It will become as simple as this (sample from their website):

```
$('.money2').mask("#.##0,00", {reverse: true, maxlength: false});
```

Comment: That's a good one! Not exactly what I was looking for, but interesting plugin!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
This must solve your problem.

```
$.validator.addMethod("mynumber", function (value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || /^\d+(\,\d{1,2})?$/.test(value);
}, "Por favor, introduza um número válido.");
```

Thanks